# Getting nan for loss function when using StandardScalar instead of MinMax

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am currently running a neural network for regression with one hidden layer. When I use MinMax Scaler I do not get the nan's for the loss function but I get a spike at epoch 65. That is why I would like to normalize using Standard Scaler.

Train on 2456 samples, validate on 614 samples:

MinMax:

```
Epoch 1/200
2456/2456 [==============================] - 1s 208us/sample - loss: 792.2849 - accuracy: 0.5297 - val_loss: 132.7681 - val_accuracy: 0.5228
Epoch 65/200
2456/2456 [==============================] - 0s 21us/sample - loss: 215.0770 - accuracy: 0.4919 - val_loss: 12554.3564 - val_accuracy: 0.0033
Epoch 200/200
2456/2456 [==============================] - 0s 20us/sample - loss: 331.2774 - accuracy: 0.3103 - val_loss: 44.3924 - val_accuracy: 0.5212
```

StandardScaler:

```
Epoch 1/200
2456/2456 [==============================] - 0s 22us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5297 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5228
...
Epoch 200/200
2456/2456 [==============================] - 0s 12us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5297 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5228
```

```
in: x_train
out:array([[-0.82125176, -0.73628742, -0.22547625, ..., -0.15796663,
        -0.75079814,  0.00855544],
       [-0.82125176, -0.73628742, -0.22547625, ..., -0.15796663,
        -0.75079814,  0.00855544],
       [-0.82125176, -0.73628742, -0.22547625, ..., -0.15796663,
        -0.75079814,  0.00855544],
       ...,
       [ 0.90140878,  1.14083087, -0.22547625, ..., -0.02445519,
         1.41760241,  0.09675613],
       [ 0.76359594,  1.14083087,  0.3660863 , ...,  0.30325472,
         1.09146087, -0.01575742],
       [-0.82125176, -0.73628742, -0.22547625, ..., -0.15796663,
        -0.75079814,  0.00855544]])
```

This is not a problem when I am use MinMaxScaler

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

#classification problems (class labels)
#not stratifying want to keep distribution underlying the data 
#x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, stratify = y, random_state=42)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
#minmax linearly shifting between zero and 1 can make (-1,1) stdscalar is scaling with respect to std.
scaler1 = MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = StandardScaler()
scaler2.fit(x_train)
x_train = scaler2.transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler2.transform(x_test)#SCALAR LOOKS AT TRAINING DATA LEARNS WHAT TO SCALE




model = tf.keras.Sequential()
#regukarize model to reduce size of coeff. 
#128 UNITS IN LAYER
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(9,), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
#loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error
model.compile(optimizer = opt, 
              loss = loss,
             metrics = ["accuracy"])
#DEFINE THEN COMPILE MODEL


model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=200, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

In terms of data, the following are the head(10) and tail(5) of the dataframe I turned into a numpy.array of x: (3070,9) and y: (3070,1). I used the PAL column for my 'Y' values and wanted to predict them by using an 'X' matrix consisting of all the other columns in the dataframe minus the PAL column and the Players column.

```
Position    eFG%    iFG Reb Ast T/O Blk PF  PER*    PAL
0   PG  0.562   0.30    6.8 10.5    3.3 0.8 5.0 22.8    3.205000
1   SG  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
2   SF  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
3   PF  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
4   C   0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
5   PG  0.465   0.24    7.1 9.3 3.5 0.3 5.7 16.7    -0.125000
6   SG  0.500   0.25    4.3 5.3 4.3 0.4 3.9 11.5    1.271667
7   SF  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
8   PF  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
9   C   0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
3065    PG  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
3066    SG  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
3067    SF  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
3068    PF  0.000   0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
3069    C   0.577   0.52    16.9    4.3 2.4 2.1 6.8 25.7    3.658333
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
Edit: I put more info about my dataset.

Comment: can you upload the data?

Comment: makis, do you want to entire dataframe? I just added the first 10 and last 5 rows but all the other columns are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the SGD or (Standard Gradient Descent) optimizer try using RMSProp (Root Mean Squared Prop). In my case, this resolved the problem.